# Simulate button click

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I simulate a **visual** click on a button in my form (WinForms)?

I don't mean:

`Button_Press(MyButton, new KeyPressEventArgs());`

I want the user to see (visually) the button being clicked.

Of course I don't want to use

```
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
```

or other functions of this kind.

Comment: What technology are you using? WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET? Silverlight?

Comment: He (or she?) already mentioned that.

Comment: animated gif? maybe im missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a RadioButton instead of a normal Button, you can set its .Appearance property to "Button" and then modify its .Checked property from somewhere else.

eg.

```
this.radioButton1.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
```

and then call:

```
this.radioButton1.Checked = true;
```

or

```
this.radioButton1.Checked = false;
```

It will look just like a regular button.

Comment: I'm interested if there is a way to do so with normal buttons.
thanks anyway.

Answer (score 18):

```
Button1.PerformClick
```

Very easy one liner. Here you go.

Answer (score 2):

There is no clean way to do this. The only way I'm aware of is to use the `mouse_event` function from `user32.dll`. This also requires that you temporarily move the cursor to the desired location, perform the click, then move it back.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, 
 CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, 
    long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);

private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

public void ClickMouseLeftButton(Point globalLocation)
{
    Point currLocation = Cursor.Position;

    Cursor.Position = globalLocation;

    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 
        globalLocation.X, globalLocation.Y, 0, 0);

    Cursor.Position = currLocation;
}

public void ClickControl(Control target, Point localLocation)
{
    ClickMouseLeftButton(target.PointToScreen(localLocation));
}

public void ClickControl(Control target)
{
    ClickControl(target, new Point(target.Width / 2, target.Height / 2));
}
```

Alternatively, you could turn this into an extension method:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, 
     CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, 
        long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

    private static void ClickMouseLeftButton(Point globalLocation)
    {
        Point currLocation = Cursor.Position;

        Cursor.Position = globalLocation;

        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 
            globalLocation.X, globalLocation.Y, 0, 0);

        Cursor.Position = currLocation;
    }

    public static void ClickMouse(this Control target, Point localLocation)
    {
        ClickMouseLeftButton(target.PointToScreen(localLocation));
    }

    public static void ClickMouse(this Control target)
    {
        ClickMouse(target, new Point(target.Width / 2, target.Height / 2));
    }
}
```

This will allow you to call `controlName.ClickMouse();`

Comment: SendInput from user32.dll can be used in a similar way, with similar caveats about it moving the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 2):

You could always try [White](http://white.codeplex.com/).  I've observed it moving the mouse pointer and visibly clicking on Silverlight UI elements in my automated UI tests; I imagine the same would happen with WinForms but I can't say for certain.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a ridiculously simple solution:

```
button1.Focus();
SendKeys.Send(" ");
```

Comment: Which doesn't visually emulate the clicking of the button (as the OP asked for).