# I want to automatically press a button on the form as soon as it is opened

Tags: c#

In the program, I have an alert that appears to the user when the first time he opens the program, if it has expired products, an alert message appears like this
[image]

If the user presses yes, the screen will open with the products that have expired during the week
This screen opens

[image]

Here are his options 3 options that he sees the end of the day or to end during the current month.
Automatic, so I want the first thing to press Yes, the exception to the offer opens on the button (this week) that displays the current week
The code I used

```
 if (tbl001.Rows.Count >= 1)
        {
            if (XtraMessageBox.Show("لديك منتجات ستنتهى مدة صلاحيتها خلال هذا الإسبوع هل تريد الإطلاع عليها", "تاكيد", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Frm_ProductsExpiration frm = new Frm_ProductsExpiration();
                frm.ShowDialog();
                frm.simpleButton1.PerformClick();
            }
        }
```

But unfortunately it didn't work for me. I want as soon as the screen is opened, the button I want is automatically pressed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159651/simulate-button-click/5619754

Comment: Why even have the alert dialog if all that is going to happen is the `Yes` button is pressed. Just show the final screen.

Answer (score 0):

The call to [`ShowDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog) prevents the following line, `frm.simpleButton1.PerformClick()`, from executing until after `frm` is closed.

You could just add a handler to the [`Shown` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown) on `Frm_ProductsExpiration` and call `simpleButton1.PerformClick()` there.

For example, in your existing code simply remove the call to `frm.simpleButton1.PerformClick()`.

```cs
if (tbl001.Rows.Count >= 1)
{
    if (XtraMessageBox.Show("لديك منتجات ستنتهى مدة صلاحيتها خلال هذا الإسبوع هل تريد الإطلاع عليها", "تاكيد", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Frm_ProductsExpiration frm = new Frm_ProductsExpiration();
        frm.ShowDialog();
        // Note that we've removed the call to frm.simpleButton1.PerformClick()
    }
}
```

Then, you use the designer to add a handler to the `Shown` event on `Frm_ProductsExpiration`, and call `simpleButton1.PerformClick()` there.

```cs
private void Frm_ProductsExpiration_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    simpleButton1.PerformClick();
}
```

If you can't use the designer for some reason, you could just manually add the handler in the constructor of `Frm_ProductsExpiration`.

```cs
public Frm_ProductsExpiration()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Shown += Frm_ProductsExpiration_Shown;
}

private void Frm_ProductsExpiration_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    simpleButton1.PerformClick();
}
```

Comment: A possible working example for clarification

Comment: I added some example code. Hopefully it clarifies? All you need to do is add a handler to the `Shown` event on `Frm_ProductsExpiration`, from the designer for example, then call `simpleButton1.PerformClick()` in that function. Then you can remove the `frm.simpleButton1.PerformClick()` after the `frm.ShowDialog` call.